# How should I handle @@redux/INIT action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I expected category list according to my reducer:

```
export default function categoryListReducer(state=initialState.categories, action) {        
    console.log("categoryListReducer -> ", action);
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.GET_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS:
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

But when componentDidMount function is called:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.actions.getCategories();
    this.props.actions.getProducts(this.props.currentCategory.id);
}
```

This comes up before the expected result:

[image]

How can I handle this @@redux/INIT actions?

Comment: You don't need to handle them at all. They're Redux internals. Every action is dispatched to every reducer - that's why you have a `switch` with which you handle only the ones you're interested in and just return the current state if the action doesn't interest you in that reducer.

Comment: Actually, Redux adds a random string (e.g., ``b.t.1.6.u.m.``) to the actions so that you can't handle them. ``INIT`` serves only to stimulate your reducer to return its initial state so that the tree is fully populated. ``PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTION`` ensures that all reducers have a ``default:`` that returns the current state (rather than ``undefined``) when given an unexpected action type.